# Extjs 4.2 grid to pivot

Tags: grid, pivot, converters, extjs4.2

My question is how i can convert any storage record in grid element that bind one data index into column and another into row!
Model of storage is something like

```
['RowId', 'CollumnId', 'Value', 'ValueType','isEditable']
```

I need binding

- `RowId`,`CollumnId` with some map that can show some Title instead.
- `ValueType` need for the converter in order to point converter how data should be represented.
- `isEditable` is bool value that point is this value can editable

So first i can transform records into new present

```
    [RowId: id, 
      Col1: { value1, ValueType1, isEditable1},
      Col2: {value2,ValueType2, isEditable2},
      ....,
      ColN{...}]
```

, hence i can create dynamical model and collumn for the grid, but i think that is not the way...

At this way i have some infinity problem with converters and validators, and after this how to convert editing data back, to send only changed data on the server.

## Does anybody has some ideas?

### Or any way how i can create some 'proxy' between storage and grid, that can convert raw data into needed grid model, and back?
Which point to find some hack way to call it when grid try to fill itself?